# Как создать запись связанную с другой в mysql

Tags: mysql

Допустим, я создаю две таблицы следующим образом:

```
CREATE TABLE Author (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Book (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  author_id INT,
  CONSTRAINT fk_book_author FOREIGN KEY(author_id) REFERENCES Author(id)
);
```

Теперь мне нужно чтобы при создании строки в таблице `Book` она ссылалась на другую определенную строку из таблицы `Author` (то есть чтобы добавленные книги ссылались на своего автора). Я не понимаю какой запрос нужно написать чтобы так произошло, укажите где можно об этом почитать или подскажите сами если вам не сложно.

Comment: Обычный insert. id автора вы должны передавать сами (предварительно получив его из Author), как любое другое поле. Так же обратите внимание, что в мире есть множество книг у которых более одного автора. Вы не сможете добавить их в свою структуру

Answer (score 0):

Вот к какой команде я все таки пришел:

```
INSERT INTO Book(title, author_id)
SELECT 'Евгений Онегин', Author.id FROM Author
WHERE Author.name = 'А.С. Пушкин';
```